# Convert int to CGFloat

Tags: iphone, objective-c, integer

Any idea on how to convert an `int` to `CGFloat` in Objective-C?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In the past casting a CGFloat value using the () syntax has worked fine for me. CGFloat is just defined as "typedef float CGFloat;" so you go about casting it the same way you would a float:

```
CGFloat f = (CGFloat)intVal;
```

or, if your value is a constant:

```
CGFloat f = 1.10;
```

Comment: Sadly this no longer works on 64bit, where a CGFloat is a 'double': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264924/whats-the-difference-between-using-cgfloat-and-float

Comment: If you remove the `f` suffix then it should work, there will be an implicit downcast from double to float on a 32-bit platform and no cast at all on a 64-bit one.

Answer (score 17):

i was searching in how to do the same in swift 
and i find the question in first result (high ranked) so i will post the answer if had found in case someone was lucky like me :)

```
let myCGFloat = CGFloat(myFloat)
```

Comment: Expression took 37ms to type-check (limit: 33ms)

Comment: Swift compiler takes 30+msec to compile this

Comment: @AntonDuzenko how did you get around this to bring down the type check

Comment: @AntonTheDev I didn't. It's still polluting my code. You can increase time threshold to be higher than your slowest type check or move your logic to an obj-c or c++ code. I'm running a MacOS VM - maybe native M1 environment is much faster.

Comment: @AntonDuzenko I don't know how you measure the time, it will be nice if you let us know.

Comment: -warn-long-expression-type-checking

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who's looking for a Swift option:

```swift
let cgFloat = CGFloat(integerLiteral: intVar)
```