# What's the difference between using CGFloat and float?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I tend to use CGFloat all over the place, but I wonder if I get a senseless "performance hit" with this. CGFloat seems to be something "heavier" than float, right? At which points should I use CGFloat, and what makes really the difference?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

As @weichsel stated, CGFloat is just a typedef for either `float` or `double`. You can see for yourself by Command-double-clicking on "CGFloat" in Xcode — it will jump to the CGBase.h header where the typedef is defined. The same approach is used for NSInteger and NSUInteger as well.

These types were introduced to make it easier to write code that works on both 32-bit and 64-bit without modification. However, if all you need is `float` precision within your own code, you can still use `float` if you like — it will reduce your memory footprint somewhat. Same goes for integer values.

I suggest you invest the modest time required to make your app 64-bit clean and try running it as such, since most Macs now have 64-bit CPUs and Snow Leopard is fully 64-bit, including the kernel and user applications. Apple's [64-bit Transition Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/) is a useful resource.

Comment: I think I get it now. But on the iPhone it seems to not matter much, right?

Comment: On the iPhone as we know it, no. However, it's always wise to future-proof code, and this would make it easier to safely reuse the same code for OS X.

Comment: so you're saying, basically, NEVER use a float or double directly since then you'd be tied to the processor architecture (and I thought fast JVMs solved this years ago :)). So what primitives are safe? `int`?

Comment: I didn't say NEVER use a primitive directly. There are times that straight primitives can be problematic, such as if a variable may conceivably be used to store data which could overflow, such as on 64-bit. In general, using architecture-dependent typedefs is safer, in that code is less likely to explode on a different architecture. However, sometimes using a 32-bit type can be completely safe and save you memory.

The size of primitives may be less of an issue in a JVM, but Obj-C and C are compiled, and mixing 32 and 64 bit libraries and code is indeed problematic.

Comment: @QuinnTaylor can you provide a practical example of how float would overflow while CGFloat would not? Both float and CGFloat have a finite number of bits. You can overflow both of them by needing to store more bits than they can hold.

Comment: One place this overflows is when using float/double as method return values like (double)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. That will cause problems on 32-bit systems while working fine on 64-bit systems, thus being extremely hard to find/debug. The solution is to use CGFloat here. This is arguably a slightly contrived example, but a valid one.

Answer (score 78):

CGFloat is a regular float on 32-bit systems
and a double on 64-bit systems

```
typedef float CGFloat;// 32-bit
typedef double CGFloat;// 64-bit
```

So you won't get any performance penalty.

Comment: Well, you use twice as much memory, if you're worried about memory.

Comment: Correct, iPhone OS is 32-bit. If you think about it, the iPhone isn't pushing the 4GB RAM limitation of 32-bit, nor is it using an Intel processor (for which 64-bit is faster than 32-bit). Plus, it's using Modern Runtime (as opposed to Legacy Runtime of 32-bit on the desktop — wearch SO for these terms if you're curious) so it can do basically everything 64-bit OS X can. Perhaps someday we'll see a device that runs iPhone OS and is 64-bit, but currently there are none.

Comment: You won't necessarily use "twice as much memory".  In most normal situations on 64 bit architectures, you're going to align on 64 bit boundaries anyway, so if you allocated memory or define structs limited to 32 bit types, unless you personally are packing/unpacking pairs of 32 bit values into 64 bit words, you are probably going to end up with 64 bit underlying storage anyway.

Comment: 5S is now in 64 bit, last time I entered the conference (london), they said the way they run 32-bit apps on ios7 is to init another shared cache pool in memory, which can result in using more memory overall. so its def worth to convert everything up to 64-bits. (unless you want to support 5.1+ or 6.0+ still)

Comment: Is it safe to put a CGFloat into NSNumber:  `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myCGFloatVar]`

Comment: You should use `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myCGFloatVar]` because `CGFloat` is defined as `double` on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Let's add that: 1. The `32 bit float` is the correct choice where ever code consistency is required. 2. But once aligned on `64 Bit CPU` it costs the same memory as if it was 64 bit (so, 32 bits are wasted). 3. While `CGFloat` allows you to use the maximum the system has to offer!

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, CGFloat is a float on 32-bit systems and a double on 64-bit systems. However, the decision to do that was inherited from OS X, where it was made based on the performance characteristics of early PowerPC CPUs. In other words, you should not think that float is for 32-bit CPUs and double is for 64-bit CPUs. (I believe, Apple's ARM processors were able to process doubles long before they went 64-bit.)
The main performance hit of using doubles is that they use twice the memory and therefore might be slower if you are doing a lot of floating point operations.

Answer (score 3):

## Objective-C

From the Foundation source code, in CoreGraphics' `CGBase.h`:

```
/* Definition of `CGFLOAT_TYPE', `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE', `CGFLOAT_MIN', and
   `CGFLOAT_MAX'. */

#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
# define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
# define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif

/* Definition of the `CGFloat' type and `CGFLOAT_DEFINED'. */

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
#define CGFLOAT_DEFINED 1
```

<sup>Copyright (c) 2000-2011 Apple Inc.</sup>

This is essentially doing:

```
#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
typedef double CGFloat;
#else
typedef float CGFloat;
#endif
```

Where [`__LP64__`](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html) indicates whether the current architecture* is 64-bit.

Note that 32-bit systems can still use the 64-bit `double`, it just takes more processor time, so CoreGraphics does this for optimization purposes, not for compatibility. If you aren't concerned about performance but are concerned about accuracy, simply use `double`.

## Swift

In Swift, [`CGFloat`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat) is a `struct` wrapper around either `Float` on 32-bit architectures or `Double` on 64-bit ones (You can detect this at run- or compile-time with [`CGFloat.NativeType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/nativetype)) and [`cgFloat.native`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/1455813-native).

From the CoreGraphics source code, [in `CGFloat.swift.gyb`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/11246be177a40d2affc8efa18a8d9e2abf23c8cc/stdlib/public/Darwin/CoreGraphics/CGFloat.swift.gyb#L27-L35):

```swift
public struct CGFloat {
#if arch(i386) || arch(arm)
  /// The native type used to store the CGFloat, which is Float on
  /// 32-bit architectures and Double on 64-bit architectures.
  public typealias NativeType = Float
#elseif arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64)
  /// The native type used to store the CGFloat, which is Float on
  /// 32-bit architectures and Double on 64-bit architectures.
  public typealias NativeType = Double
#endif
```

---

<sup>*Specifically, `long`s and pointers, hence the `LP`. See also: http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html</sup>

Comment: CGFloat also has an instance property called `native` that returns self in the native type (Float or Double as specified above).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @PeterSchorn! Not sure why I didn't mention it in the answer

Answer (score 2):

just mention that - Jan, 2020 Xcode 11.3/iOS13

**Swift 5**

From the CoreGraphics source code

```
public struct CGFloat {
    /// The native type used to store the CGFloat, which is Float on
    /// 32-bit architectures and Double on 64-bit architectures.
    public typealias NativeType = Double
```

Comment: So CGFloat is always a Double as of Swift 5?