# CGFloat argument type incorrectly traces out with zero value...why?

Tags: objective-c, debugging

Really puzzled why the following is happening and hope someone can help.

// here xPos correctly traces out, always changing

```
 //CODE EXCERPT
 CGFloat xPos=currentTouchPosition.x - lastTouch.x;

   NSLog(@"touchesMoved and xPos= %f", xPos);

    if (startTouchPosition.x < currentTouchPosition.x)
     [self adjustTimer:xPos];
    else
```

//here newInterval always traces as 0...why????

```
-(void) adjustTimer:(CGFloat)newInterval
{
 NSLog(@" adjustTimer and newInterval = %f",newInterval);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this and I think I figured out why this happens. As mentioned, using `double` in the method call can solve this depending on how your code is compiled, but there is a reason why this happens.

[This stack page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264924/whats-the-difference-between-using-cgfloat-and-float) explains the differences CGFloat and a float. Effectively CGFloat is a typedef "wrapper" around either a float or a double. Whether it actually is a float or a double depends on the header where CGFloat is defined that your code compiled against. According to the aforementioned page, you can actually view this header (`CGBase.h`) by right clicking on `CGFloat` in the code editor and going to "Jump to Definition". You'll see something like this:

```
/* Definition of `CGFLOAT_TYPE', `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE', `CGFLOAT_MIN', and
   `CGFLOAT_MAX'. */

#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
# define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
# define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif

/* Definition of the `CGFloat' type and `CGFLOAT_DEFINED'. */

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
#define CGFLOAT_DEFINED 1
```

Notice the line:

```
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
```

This constant nested in those tags define whether a CGFloat is a double or float, which according to the `#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__` seems to depend on whether the architecture is 64 bit or not. Which when you think about it, is a good idea for increasing precision depending on your machine's architecture.

All goes well until you mix code compiled with this flag on, with other code compiled with this flag off (Such as a binary library with other code). Effectively mixing 64 bit compiled code with 32 bit compiled code. This causes messages getting passed doubles to methods expecting a float. Since this is all happening at the byte level, no error is thrown and the bytes are just truncated, taking off all of the bits that actually described your value and leaving bits with nothing in them, or 0.

Beware that this can happen easily when mixing code compiled for OS X with code compiled for iOS, but can even happen with code compiled just for iOS, when you compile a binary for both the Simulator and Device.

Comment: If I'm following what you're saying, doing a clean between compiles for simulator and compiles for device should fix this. Right?

Comment: Depends. I had some weird build settings when I was doing this, so I was building against the simulator headers for production. I explicitly changed my `CGFloat`s to either `double` or `float` to signal to the compiler that their needed to be a translation layer between CGFloats, which the C mojo underneath does automatically. I can't think of a way off hand that a simple clean would fix the problem I was having, but your build settings may vary. Maybe?

Comment: If your finding that your passing CGFloats between custom libraries, it might be a good policy to use `int`, `float` and `double` explicitly, instead of using some kind of wrapper type. (`NSInteger`, `CGFloat`, `NSTimeInterval` come to mind as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok resolved by changing the method argument type to 'double' from CGFloat, but confused as to why this works.

Comment: Under 32-bit, `CGFloat` is a `float`, which can lead to problems when types aren't explicitly known. (I know I've been bitten by this before.)

Comment: Same problem is happening to me. How is it possible to fix that?