# Use CGFloat instead of float? They don't do it

Tags: objective-c, cgfloat

[I might be misunderstanding this entire topic, as I've grown up with languages that allow the dev to almost entirely ignore processor architecture, like Java, except in some particular cases. **Please correct me if I have some of the concepts wrong.**]

Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264924/whats-the-difference-between-using-cgfloat-and-float) it seems that the advice is to use CGFloat instead of, say, float, because it future-proofs my code for different processor architectures (64-bit handles float differently). Assuming that is right, then why does `UISlider`, for instance, use `float` directly (for the value)? **Wouldn't it be wrong (or something) for me to read their `float` and convert it to a `CGFloat`, because in any case my code is not right if the architecture changes anyway?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CGFloat` is just a `typedef` for `float`. This provides flexibility for `CGFloat` to be something different down the road. Which is why using it future-proofs your code. Objective-C does this with many types, `NSInteger` is another example.

Although they can be used interchangeably, I agree that it doesn't appear in the case of `UISlider` that Apple was *dogfooding*.

Comment: +1 so what do you think the implications are for code that reads from and writes to a value on a slider? Just use float?

Comment: I say if it's a `float` use `float` ;) Consistency is what matters here. Ideally it would be `CGFloat` throughout.

Answer (score 2):

CGFloat is part of Core Graphics, and used for things like pixel values, which has changed greatly over the years (anyone here a TRS-80 lover?). SO, using CGFloat for display-related drawing values is advised.

The value of the slider is not graphics-related. It is simply 0.0 to 1.0, which can be handled precisely by a float, and probably a 16-bit float at that.

Comment: So float is float is float, even if the architecture changes?

Comment: what float actually is depends on the architecture (refer to endianess). From a programming perspective, you can always be guaranteed that it will 'work' the same way. Similarly, CGFloat will always give you good result for computer-graphic related computations, no matter what the actual display and architecture.