# Tableview height for row return type warning

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

Running Xcode 5.1 (7.1 beta) on the iPad Retina 64bit simulator, I am required to change the return type to 'double', when on a device with 7.1 beta I have to change it to 'float'. If I run the app without changing the type, the cell height is effectively 0. Has anyone else seen or had this problem before? I cannot find any information about it online.

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([lastSelectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        return 310.0;
    } else {
        return 120.0;
    }
}
```

[image: Compiler warning]

Comment: Hey dude, you simply replace the return type in the first line from `float` to `CGFloat`. Check my post to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is replace the method line from

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//^^^^^ The return type is incorrect, the whole line needs to be replaced
```

with

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This is because Apple's default delegate method for the heightForRowAtindexPath requires the use of CGFloat instead of float. You can also double check future delegate methods you may implement by going into your .h file, and right clicking on the UITableViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource protocol to see Apple's full list of method constructions and how they should be called, used and what their return types are.

**More information about using `CGFloat` instead of `float` in response to Wain's comment.**
From the post [Why to use CGFloat instead of float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214135/use-cgfloat-instead-of-float-they-dont-do-it)

*"CGFloat is just a typedef for float. This provides flexibility for CGFloat to be something different down the road. Which is why using it future-proofs your code. Objective-C does this with many types, NSInteger is another example."* - Jason McReary.

So Apple likes using these type-defs and encourage developers to do the same so that your code can be future proof in case the underlying architecture changes in how floats are handled.

Comment: You should describe the difference between `float` and `CGFloat` - why does it matter?

Comment: @Wain Good idea, I will do. Give me a sec and I'll update my post. Thanks Wain

Comment: Lol, I should actually be using type-defs too, it was only through your comment that I now fully understand why to go the extra mile to type the two `CG` or `NS` characters for floats, numbers and the like; I'm currently thinking of revisiting all my code and update now! lol

Comment: It looks like they are tightening up their use on primitive c types. I have been using float for forever. The info you provided explains why. Thanks!

Comment: @HobbestheTige I just understood now myself! Pretty cool what you can find out when someone asks a simple question as `is that so hey? can you explain why that is the case?`. 
No problem man.

Answer (score 3):

Your method should return a `CGFloat` value, not a `float`.