# iOS 8.1 and 8.2 uitableviewcells are stacked on top of each other but not in 8.3

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8.1

Any thoughts? Kind of weird, I've never see this before.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail about how this table is setup.

Answer (score 2):

How is the row height set? Assuming you have auto layout configured for your custom table view cells correctly.You might consider setting the following properties.

```
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;
   self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 50;
   self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Hard to determine what might be wrong with the info provided in the question, but hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

for
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

replace with

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

replace float with CGFloat , it worked for me...

Comment: Can you explain why this worked? Just supplying code rarely answers a question as the asker doesn't necessarily know what the code means.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264924/whats-the-difference-between-using-cgfloat-and-float
This would help. After updating the XCode to 8.3 this happened.

Comment: thank you for this answer! This was exactly the issue, everything seemed fine on iOS 8.4, 8.3 and 7.1, but an iPad with 8.1 had all the tableviewcells stacked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a height constraint on the uiviewcell but it's still odd it worked fine in 7.1 and 8.3. Thanks.